# Axios fail to attach cookies from previous post request

Tags: axios, httprequest

I am trying to send request from `axios` like below:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";
import * as os from 'os';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as FormData from 'form-data';
/**
 * Prefetch QRCode https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode
 * Get QRCode https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode/${token}/image
 * Query ScanInfo https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode/${token}/scan_info
 */
const qrCodeUrl = "https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode";
const uDIDUrl = 'https://www.zhihu.com/udid';
export class ZhihuService{
    
    public async login(){
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("知乎登陆");
        await this.qrcodeLogin();
    }
    protected async qrcodeLogin() {
        var api = axios.create({
            withCredentials: true
        });
        //pre-hand before get qrcode token
        api.post(uDIDUrl, null,{
            withCredentials:true
        }).then(res =>{
            console.log(api);
            console.log(res.data);
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        });
        await api.post(qrCodeUrl, null,{
            withCredentials:true
        }).catch((error: any) =>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

For `api.post(uDIDUrl`, it return expected result.

But for second request, it always return 403, If I test these two reqeust url in postman, it works
Checking the error in second request, I could see the cookies from first request response did not auto attach.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to add `await` into `api.post(uDIDUrl`  like you did in `await api.post(qrCodeUrl`. So in theory it will wait the response and get the cookies before you call the second post request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you should wait for the first call before doing the second one. Either `await` on the first one or perform the second one in the `then` clause of the first call, since they depend on one another.

```
// A Promise will be returned for POST uDIDUrl (never assigned anywhere) and execution will continue
api.post(uDIDUrl, null,{
    withCredentials:true
}).then(res =>{
    console.log(api);
    console.log(res.data);
}).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
});

// The execution will block until the returned Promise of the `POST qrCodeUrl` request is fulfilled
await api.post(qrCodeUrl, null,{
    withCredentials:true
}).catch((error: any) =>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I have tried boath await api.post(uDIDUrl) or await api.post(uDIDUrl).then with api.post(qrCodeUrl), both not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is both API calls are running parallelly. Since `qrCodeUrl` depends on `uDIDUrl's` response,
you should wait for the first API call to finish first.

For this you have two options:

1. Do your `qrCodeUrl` API call inside then block of `uDIDUrl`
2. Use await in `uDIDUrl` request. (Prefer this because you already have async function `qrcodeLogin`)

Also, you don't need to add `withCredentials` again, since you have written it once while initialising axios instance.

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";
import * as os from 'os';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as FormData from 'form-data';

/**
 * Prefetch QRCode https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode
 * Get QRCode https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode/${token}/image
 * Query ScanInfo https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode/${token}/scan_info
 */
const qrCodeUrl = "https://www.zhihu.com/api/v3/account/api/login/qrcode";
const uDIDUrl = 'https://www.zhihu.com/udid';

export class ZhihuService {

  public async login() {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("知乎登陆");
    await this.qrcodeLogin();
  }

  protected async qrcodeLogin() {
    var api = axios.create({
      withCredentials: true
    });
    
    //pre-hand before get qrcode token
    await api.post(uDIDUrl).then(res => {      // Added await here & removed extra parameters
      console.log(api);
      console.log(res.data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    await api.post(qrCodeUrl).catch((error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried boath `await api.post(uDIDUrl)` or `await api.post(uDIDUrl).then` with `api.post(qrCodeUrl)`, both not work.

Comment: @Edward can you share a codepen please. It would be easer to navigate and fix.

Answer (score -1):

I think the two requests happens at the same time, not after each other.

Comment: even if I move the second request to first request then block, it still error.